# Capistrano deploy error: Stage not set

Tags: ruby, deployment, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm, capistrano

I followed [this](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/28/setup-a-ubuntu-vps-for-hosting-ruby-on-rails-applications-2/) tutorial to set up rvm, ruby, rails, nginx and passenger. I then installed capistrano and node.js. Now, everything works fine up to the point where I try to deploy *test_app.*

```
cap deploy:setup
```

creates the following error:

```
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
Stage not set, please call something such as `cap production deploy`, where production is a stage you have defined.
```

now

```
cap production deploy
```

creates this error:

```
cap aborted!
RVM - Capistrano integration was extracted to a separate gem, install: `gem install rvm-capistrano` and remove the `$LOAD_PATH.unshift` line, note also the 'set :rvm_type, :user' is now the default (instead of :system).
/home/USER/.rvm/lib/rvm/capistrano.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
config/deploy.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:12:in `load'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => production
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

So I did what was suggested, installed rvm-capistrano and removed *$:.unshift(File.expand_path('./lib', ENV['rvm_path']))*, which created the following error:

```
cap production deploy
cap aborted!
Unable to activate rvm-capistrano-1.5.1, because capistrano-3.0.1 conflicts with capistrano (~> 2.15.4)
config/deploy.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:12:in `load'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/setup.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/lib/capistrano/application.rb:12:in `run'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/capistrano-3.0.1/bin/cap:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/cap:23:in `load'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => production
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try running `bundle exec cap production deploy`

Comment: This creates the following error:

`/home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:214:in 'block in replace_gem': capistrano is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
 from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/cap:22:in '<main>'
 from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in 'eval'
 from /home/USER/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in '<main>'
`

Comment: Do you have a `Gemfile` in the folder?

Comment: Wrong question. It looks like you do. Edit that file and add "capistrano" and run `bundle` on the terminal

Comment: Now it does this:


`bundle exec cap production deploy
cap aborted!
cannot load such file -- rvm/capistrano
...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

right now there are two gems that work with capistrano3 / rvm1:

- https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
- https://github.com/rvm/rvm1-capistrano3 (I'm author of this one)

I have already discussed merging both gems (use `rvm1-capistrano3` in `capistrano/rvm`).

You can also open a ticket for rvm to point out to the new gems => https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues